# Creating Crash Log for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, logging, crash, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on Windows phone 8.1 app, I need to log all the exception and some information to a file and also console at the same time.

1.How can I do that?

2.Is there any third party for that?

I need to send that log file when ever the app crashes.

Comment: The store does provide stack traces for crashes by default

Answer (score 0):

You could use HockeyApp. It stores crash report and sends it to the server next time user start the application. It completely free (Microsoft has acquired HockeyApp) and provides SDK for Window Phone / Windows Store platform.

http://hockeyapp.net/features/crashreports/